# AS3 controlling movieclip of children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've few movieclip from library that will add to stage, inside of the movieclip have some mc that I want to control it, here is my script.

```
if (selectDiffText.text == "Collection 1 Easy")
    {
        var c1_easy:cartoonEasy = new cartoonEasy();
        addChild(c1_easy);
        c1_easy.x = 412;
        c1_easy.y = 400;
        TweenMax.from(c1_easy, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
    else if (selectDiffText.text == "Collection 1 Medium")
    {
        var c1_medium:cartoonMedium = new cartoonMedium();
        addChild(c1_medium);
        c1_medium.x = 412;
        c1_medium.y = 400;
        TweenMax.from(c1_medium, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
else
    {
        trace("ERROR!");
    }
```

Code above will load particular movieclip from library if the ***selectDiffText*** change.

```
var movieList:Array = [cartoonMedium1,cartoonMedium2,cartoonMedium3,cartoonMedium4,cartoonMedium5,cartoonMedium6];

function getRandomMovie():MovieClip
{
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieList.length);
    var mcClass:Class = movieList.splice(index,1)[0];
    return new mcClass();
}
playGame = getRandomMovie();
addChild(playGame);
```

let say if c1_medium is added to stage, c1_medium will also randomly added 1 of the movieclip from library on it.

inside of the ***playGame*** mc, I've *mouseTarget.alpha = 0;*...how can I control it from root level? c1_easy also have the mouseTarget.alpha=0 too.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting this code to do?

Comment: each of the c1_easy and c1_medium have the mc called mouseTarget, but each time I just loaded either c1_easy or c1_medium to the stage only. I want to control the alpha value of the mouseTarget.

The level is like this Stage>c1_easy/c1_medium>playGame

what i want is from root/stage to control mouseTarget which in playGame which added by either c1_easy or c1_medium

Answer (score 0):

To do this easily, `c1_easy` and `c1_medium` should both extend the same class.  For example:

```
class c1_easy extends CartoonGenericClass{[...]}
```

and

```
class c1_medium extends CartoonGenericClass{[...]}
```

In `CartoonGenericClass`, you would have the variable `mouseTarget`.  You make this public using the getter/setter:

```
protected var _mouseTarget:Number;

public function get mouseTarget():Number{
    return _mouseTarget;
}

public function set mouseTarget(value:Number):void{
    // (should probably do some verification on "value" here)
    _mouseTarget.alpha = value;
}
```

This will allow access to the variable `mouseTarget` (note that there is no underscore) from any object that can access either `c1_easy` or `c1_medium`:

```
c1_easy.mouseTarget = 0;
c1_medium.mouseTarget = .3;
```

etc. etc.  This is standard OOP, so it may be time to crack a doc.  HTH!

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar to code in classes...anyway to make it coded in timeline? I'm not coding in timeline not very good...

Comment: Sure, I guess.  Not the same method, but you can access whatever is in any object that is on the stage by going through the root object . . . all display objects have access to it.  I haven't done that in a while, but I think the format would be `_root.c1_whatever.mouseTarget`.  However, you have to be careful to add `c1_whatever` to the root, and not to some other object.  So: `_root.addChild(c1_whatever)`.  All this tells me, though, is that you will gain *vast* benefit from learning ActionScript 3.0.  Try using FlashDevelop to start out, and read some "Hello world" tutorials to get started.